# Try/Except...try everything even if error

Tags: python, exception, try-except

I am trying to find a way I can try every statement in a single try statement.

For example:

```
try:
  funct1()
  funct2()
  funct3()
except:
   print("expected")
```

The `try/except` is expected in my case, because one of the functions will fail.
How can I do this without multiple `try/except`s or what is the best way to do this?

In the current situation, if funct2 fails, `funct3` won't run.

Comment: did you try to use try-except in functions?

Comment: Are you really expecting them to throw an exception?

Comment: I am. Please read the comment I made below. It clarifies everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put the `try/except` in a loop:

```
for funct in (funct1, funct2, funct3):
    try:
       funct()
    except Exception:  # Catch something more specific if you can.
       print("expected")
```

This will ensure that all of the functions are executed, even if one or more raises an exception.

Comment: This does not work in my case. Let me clarify. Each function is randomWidgetNameGoesHere.destroy(). I do not get 'expected' in my terminal just a nasty error. Please read the comment I made below to qqvc for a broader understanding.

Comment: You could put your widgets in a list and then iterate over that, calling the `destroy` method on each inside the `try:` block.  Or, even better, put them all in the same container widget if you can.  Then, you just need to destroy the parent.

Comment: Putting all the widgets in the same container is great. I just don't know how to do it. So I did try/excepts. Thank you though I'll look that up.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, use *try-except* blocks in functions. Because, they are catching errors between bunch of codes.In a big program, it will be a problem if you try to catch the all errors in one.So, define your *try-except* blocks in your functions, more clear and usefull.

Comment: I should clarify. I am doing this to delete widgets in a Tkinter GUI program. When you open the program, there are three options. Each option has a bunch of entryboxes, labels, etc. I was looking for a way to destroy all of the widgets in each one. Problem is I resorted to a try/except way to try for all the widgets because I don't know how to put all the widgets into a frame, and then just delete the frame.

Comment: My advice is, just put try-except block when you think it should be an error.Its better in my opinion.If you have to use 10times, then use 10 times. So in your program, put your widgets between try-except blocks. But if you catch ALL of the errors, it must be a headache for you. You will be not able to see what is wrong with your program.

Comment: There can be an error anywhere because the user can pick the options in the GUI at random.

Comment: I mean ok - right now i have a "cleanup" function to delete all of the widgets. I am just going to put a try/except in between each one. I do not like this solution though. I hope someone could give me a better one.

Comment: try-except blocks never do anything bad in codes they just catching errors so doesnt matter how many times you using them, so as I said its my opinion its better use them whenever you want,for me Im doing this.

Comment: I ended up doing this. Thank you.